# JS Regex match string with $

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write something that would look at tweets and pull up info about stocks being mentioned in the tweet. People use $ to reference stock symbols on twitter but I cant escape the $.

I also dont want to match any price mention or anything like that so basically match $AAPL and not $1500

I was thinking it would be something like this

```
\b\$[a-zA-Z].*\b
```

if there are multiple matches id like to loop through them somehow so something like

```
while ((tweet = reg.exec(sym_pat)) !== null) {
   //replace text with stock data.
}
```

This expression gives me an unexpected illegal token error

```
 var symbol_pat = new RegExp(\b\$[a-z]*);
```

Thanks for the help if you want to see the next issue I ran into 
[Javascript AJAX scope inside of $.each Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645706/javascript-ajax-scope-inside-of-each-scope)

Comment: You're on the right track, but you should drop the dot. You want to match repeating `[a-zA-Z]`, not just any character (`.`) after a single occurrence of `[a-zA-Z]`, right?

Comment: Also, put a plus sign to the char. group to make it match not only a single char. element `[a-zA-Z]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var symbol_pat = new RegExp('\\b\\$[a-z]+\\b','gi');
// or
var symbol_pat = /\b\$[a-z]+\b/gi;
```

Also, for some reason JS can not calculate the beginning of a word by `\b`, it just catches the one at the end.

**EDIT:** If you're replacing the stock symbols you can use the basic `replace` method by a function and replace that data with predefined values:

```
var symbol_pat = /(^|\s)(\$[a-z]+\b)/gi;
var stocks = {AAPL:1,ETC:2}
var str = '$aapl ssd $a a$s$etc $etc';
console.log(str);
str = str.replace(symbol_pat, function() {
    var stk = arguments[2].substr(1).toUpperCase();
    // assuming you want to replace $etc as well as $ETC by using
    // the .toUpperCase() method
    if (!stocks[stk]) return arguments[0];
    return arguments[0].replace(arguments[2],stocks[stk]);
});
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, you've stated that you want to replace the matches with their actual stock values. So, you need to get all of the matching elements (stock ticker names) and then for each match you're going to replace the it with the stock value.

The answer will "read" very similarly to that sentence.

Assume there's a `tweet` variable that is the contents of a particular tweet you're going to work on:

```
tweet.match(/\b\$[A-Za-z]+\b/g).forEach(function(match) {
    // match looks like '$AAPL'
    var tickerValue = lookUpTickerValue(match);
    tweet.replace(match, tickerValue);
});
```

This is assuming you have some logic somewhere that will grab the ticker value for the given stock name and then replace it (it should probably return the original value if it can't find a match, so you don't mangle lovely tweets like "Barbara Streisand is $ATAN").